# how do i set a conditional statement here?

Tags: php

```
<ul>
    <li class="artist-website"><a href="<?php=$artist_website?>" target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li class="artist-youtube"><a href="http://youtube.com/<?php=$artist_youtube?>" target="_blank"></a></li>
    <li class="artist-twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/<?php=$artist_twitter?>" target="_blank"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to add an if exists statement before each of the 'li' items. For example, if "artist-website" exists, then echo `<li class="artist-website"><a href="<?php=$artist_website?>" target="_blank"></a></li>`

How can I do make this work?

Comment: do you want to validate if the varible has a value or if the actual page is online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ul>
  <?php if(isset($artist_website){ ?> <li class="artist-website">...</li> <?php } ?>
  ...
</ul>
```

Or `if(!empty($artist_website))`, depending how your variables are setup.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
<?php if (/* exists */) : ?>
    <li class="artist-website"><a href="<?php echo $artist_website ?>" target="_blank"></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you clarify what I need to type in the part where you wrote /* exists */ ? That's where I'm having trouble. Do I just put in `$artist_website`?

Comment: @J82 Totally depends what you want to check. If you want to check whether the variable exists, use `isset($artist_website)`. If you also want to check whether it's `false`-y, use `empty($artist_website)`. If you're sure the variable exists and just want to check if it's `true`, use simply `$artist_website`.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I understand what you're asking. Here is a link showing how to check if a website is available. The other 2 comments mainly showed you how to set up the if statement.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/check-if-website-is-available/

EDIT: unless you are checking if a variable is set or not... then it would be:

```
if (isset($var)) {

// do this

}
```